# Moodle SCORM SQL

Tags: sql, moodle, scorm

What table and field I need to use in SQL to find SCORM activities that reports back score to Moodle and exclude the SCORM objects that are set as non scoring. Basically looking for the SCORM settings field: **Require Minimum Score** in SQL

The query:

```
    SELECT
    CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname ) AS 'fullname', 
    cc.name AS 'Category',
    c.fullname AS 'Course', 
    gi.itemname AS 'Item Name',
    ROUND(gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100 ,2) AS 'Percentage',
    asgm.status as 'Status',
    p.status AS 'Completed',
    gi.itemmodule as 'Type',
    s.completionscorerequired AS require_minimum_score
    FROM prefix_course AS c
    JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category
    JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
    JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
    JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
    JOIN prefix_grade_items AS gi ON gi.courseid = c.id
    JOIN prefix_scorm AS s ON c.id = s.course
    LEFT JOIN prefix_grade_grades AS gg ON gi.id = gg.itemid AND gg.userid = u.id
    LEFT JOIN prefix_course_completions AS p ON p.userid = u.id AND p.course = c.id
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT asgm.status as status, c.id as cid, u.id as uid,  gi.id as giid
      FROM prefix_course AS c
           JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category
           JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
           JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
           JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
           JOIN prefix_grade_items AS gi ON gi.courseid = c.id
           JOIN prefix_assign AS asg ON gi.iteminstance = asg.id and asg.course = c.id
           JOIN prefix_assign_submission AS asgm ON asg.id = asgm.assignment and asgm.userid = u.id 
      ) AS asgm ON c.id = asgm.cid and u.id = asgm.uid  and gi.id = asgm.giid

    WHERE (gi.itemmodule = 'quiz' OR gi.itemmodule= 'assign' OR gi.itemmodule= 'scorm') AND c.visible=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.id AS scormid, s.name AS scormname,
       s.completionscorerequired AS require_minimum_score,
       c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename
FROM mdl_scorm s
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = s.course
```

Comment: Thanks Russell. helpful as usual

Comment: Strange but when I combine a SCORM object that requires minimum score and another SCORM object that doesn't require a score, both in same subject, the report shows the non-require score as required score with same value, 100 in this example. This issue happens when adding the scorm table to the user enrollment assignment, however in the script Russel typed above, this error doesnt happen?

Comment: If you are using $DB->get_record_sql() then the first column needs to be unique. The first column is a key, so in the case above this is firstname + lastname. So if if there is more than one scorm or role assignment or grade_item, then its only showing the last record. I always have developer debug level on during development, it will show an error message saying the first column is not unique. Use something like `SELECT CONCAT(c.id,'_,' ra.id,'_,' u.id, '_,'gi.id, s.id) AS uniqueid` for the first column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get duplicated rows. Am not SQL expert, in fact this report been assembled from different sources and it been working perfectly expect adding the prefix_scorm table and try to exclude scorm items with scoring req=0, the report get missed up!